# Trying to use Luatex: luatex.fmt not found, etex.ini not found

Tags: miktex, luatex

I want to disclaim that I am very inexperienced with latex. I am using Texmaker 4.3 with Miktex 2.9 on Windows 7.

I am writing an article (let's call it "test") which includes several packages to generate figures. One of them is `pgfmolbio`. When doing a Quickbuild , I am getting a Latex error that the environment `pmbdomains` is not defined. I understand from the documentation of this package that I have to run `luatex` on my file in order to get it to work. Now, when running `luatex test` it tells me that luatex.fmt was not found.

However, I find luatex on the dropdown list on top in texworks. Trying to use it there I get a similar error: `I can't find the format file 'miktex-luatex.fmt'!`.

From another answer with the same problem I learned that I should try to to run `luatex -ini luatex.ini`. 
When doing so, the Miktex package manager starts. The next error I get is `I can't find etex.ini`. I couldn't find any further solution and would be happy about help.

**Edit:** here is an example that produces the said error, taken from the `pgfmolbio` [Package Manual](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[domains]{pgfmolbio}
\begin{document}
\begin{pmbdomains}[name=\TeX ase]{200}
\addfeature{disulfide}{40}{129}
\addfeature{disulfide}{53}{65}
\addfeature[description=Domain 1]{domain}{30}{80}
\addfeature[description=Domain 2]{domain}{93}{163}
\addfeature{domain}{168}{196}
\end{pmbdomains}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2:** Log file of Lualatex (I redacted the path of the file):

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012060719 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)  (format=lualatex 2014.9.10)  11 SEP 2014 14:37
**test2
("C:/.../test2.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
LuaTeX adaptation of babel <v3.8m-luatex-1.5> and hyphenation patterns for engl
ish, loaded.
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.sty"
Package: pgfmolbio 2013/08/01 v0.21 Molecular biology graphs with TikZ

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-modutils.sty"
Package: luatexbase-modutils 2010/10/10 v0.3 Module utilities for LuaTeX

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-loader.sty"
Package: luatexbase-loader 2010/10/10 v0.3 Lua module loader for LuaTeX

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-compat.sty"
Package: luatexbase-compat 2010/10/10 v0.3 Compatibility tools for LuaTeX
)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.loader.lua))
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/modutils.lua))
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs.lua)
Lua module: lualibs 2011/01/20 0.96 Lua additional functions.

(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-string.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-lpeg.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-boolean.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-number.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-math.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-table.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-aux.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-io.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-os.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-file.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-md5.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-dir.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-unicode.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-utils.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-dimen.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-url.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-set.lua)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.lua)
Lua module: pgfmolbio 2012/10/01 0.2 Molecular biology graphs wit LuaLaTeX

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/00miktex/color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex-loader.sty"
Package: luatex-loader 2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)

(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua))
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.lua)
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks14
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def"
File: dvipsnam.def 1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xcolor/svgnam.def"
File: svgnam.def 2007/01/21 v2.11 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks15
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def"
\pgfutil@abb=\box26

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex"
Package: pgfrcs 2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
))
Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/00miktex/graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex"
Package: pgfsys 2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@y=\dimen106
\pgf@xa=\dimen107
\pgf@ya=\dimen108
\pgf@xb=\dimen109
\pgf@yb=\dimen110
\pgf@xc=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count88
\c@pgf@countb=\count89
\c@pgf@countc=\count90
\c@pgf@countd=\count91
 ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg"
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Package pgfsys Info: Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def on input line 900.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def"
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2009/05/22  (rcs-revision 1.26)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
"
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2008/05/19  (rcs-revision 1.10)
)))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count92
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count93
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex"
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
 ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count94
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks20
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks21
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks22
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex"))) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count95
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2010/04/09  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen114
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen115
\pgf@picminy=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen117
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen118
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen121
\pgf@xx=\dimen122
\pgf@xy=\dimen123
\pgf@yx=\dimen124
\pgf@yy=\dimen125
\pgf@zx=\dimen126
\pgf@zy=\dimen127
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2010/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen128
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen129
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen130
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen131
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2010/09/08  (rcs-revision 1.34)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count96
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen132
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2009/06/10  (rcs-revision 1.11)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen133
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen134
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen135
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2008/04/23  (rcs-revision 1.11)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2008/11/23  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgf@max=\dimen136
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count97
) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2010/03/25  (rcs-revision 1.16)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2010/09/01  (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2010/08/27  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2008/01/17  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2009/07/02  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2010/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2010/10/22  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.
sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen137
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen138
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.
sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
)) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex"))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex"
Package: pgffor 2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen139
\pgffor@skip=\dimen140
\pgffor@stack=\toks23
\pgffor@toks=\toks24
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex"
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.
code.tex"
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2010/05/31 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count98
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen141
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen142
\tikz@lasty=\dimen143
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen144
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen145
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen146
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen147
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@tempbox=\box34
\tikztreelevel=\count99
\tikznumberofchildren=\count100
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count101
\tikz@fig@count=\count102

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex"
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2010/08/24  (rcs-revision 1.4)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count103
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count104
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count105
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count106

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarytopaths.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarypositioning.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex 2008/10/06 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarysvg.path.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarysvg.path.code.tex 2009/01/24 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibrarysvg.path.code
.tex"
File: pgflibrarysvg.path.code.tex 2009/01/24 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.6)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleparser.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleparser.code.tex 2009/01/12 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
)
\pgf@lib@svg@last@x=\dimen148
\pgf@lib@svg@last@y=\dimen149
\pgf@lib@svg@last@c@x=\dimen150
\pgf@lib@svg@last@c@y=\dimen151
\pgf@lib@svg@count=\count107
\pgf@lib@svg@max@num=\count108
))
\@pmb@toksa=\toks25
\@pmb@toksb=\toks26
 ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.domains.tex"
File: pgfmolbio.domains.tex 2013/08/01 v0.21 Protein domains
File: pgfmolbio.domains.tex 2012/10/01 v0.2 Protein Domains
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.domains.lua)
Lua module: pgfmolbio.domains 2012/10/01 0.2 Domain graphs
\pmb@magnifiedsequence@width=\skip43
))
("C:/.../test2.aux")
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count109
\scratchdimen=\dimen152
\scratchbox=\box35
\nofMPsegments=\count110
\nofMParguments=\count111
\everyMPshowfont=\toks27
\MPscratchCnt=\count112
\MPscratchDim=\dimen153
\MPnumerator=\count113
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count114
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks28
) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
! LuaTeX error ...iles/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.lua:54: atte
mpt to call field 'pack' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    ...iles/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.lua:54: in function 'getRa
nge'
    ...TeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.domains.lua:407: in function '?'
    ...TeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.domains.lua:521: in function 'setP
arameters'
    <\directlua >:1: in main chunk.
\endpmbdomains ...Domains() \fi pmbProtein = nil }
                                                  \ifpmb@dom@tikzpicture \el...
l.11 \end{pmbdomains}

? x


Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 10245 strings out of 495011
 100000,266212 words of node,token memory allocated 342 words of node memory still in use:
    nodes
   avail lists: 2:18,7:1,9:3
 13365 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+200000
 15 fonts using 602239 bytes
 63i,1n,57p,447b,239s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.

PDF statistics: 3 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You should call `lualatex` instead of `luatex`. I don't know if that will solve your problem, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you! This was one of the first things I tried but unfortunately I am getting the same error message that the environment `pmbdomains` specific to the package is not defined.

Comment: Could you post the contents of the .log file?  This sounds like a path search problem.

Comment: I added the .log file for `lualatex test2`, no .log file is generated for `luatex test2`.

Comment: Another thing I forgot: you need to add the `domains` option to the `pgfmolbio` package: `\usepackage[domains]{pgfmolbio}`.

Comment: I tried `[domains]`, as well as `[domains,convert]` but it gives the same results. Should I include it into the example given above?

Comment: Yes, you should include `[domains]`. Without it, the example does not compile. With it, the example should compile. For me it does, after fixing my TeX Live as above. The `pgfmolbio` manual (1.2 Getting Started) states (rather indirectly) that `[domains]` is to be used for examples in chapter 3 of the manual, like the example you chose.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add it when writing the example. It still won't compile both in `Luatex` as well as in `Lualatex`. However, the error message as well as the .log has changed - it has been updated in my question.

Comment: Note for users of TeX Live 2014: The example compiles starting from revision 35152 (Sep 11) which fixed the location of file `pgfmolbio.lua`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With MiKTeX 2.9, your file compiles perfectly. But perhaps you should `update` your installation: your .log file mention `LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012060719 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)` and the beginning of my .log file is

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013062821 (rev 4627)  (format=lualatex 2013.6.28)  11 SEP 2014 13:54
\write18 enabled.
```

You also can try to redo the formats (although updating will certainly do it for you). To redo formats, launch `MiKTeX Options` (Settings)  as administrator,  select the  `Formats` tab, select `LuaLaTeX` and click on `build`, as in this image:

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Looking at the error message in the log attached by the original poster, the reason why the older LuaTeX fails seems to be that `table.pack()` is not implemented. According to `texdoc luatexref-t`, "LuaTeX 0.74.0 is the first version with Lua 5.2". According to http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaFiveTwo, Lua 5.2 adds the function `table.pack()`.

Comment: Oh my, that was it - I will update more frequently in the future. Thanks to all contributors, it works now.